# Problem with executing command in python script

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, discord.py

So im trying to execute a code from a friend for a discord bot, it's a Markov bot that's started with the command b$sendsim.
When i try to execute the command it gives me this error:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "simulatedayymd.py", line 73, in on_message
    text = f.read()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 1845: invalid start byte
```

It works on Windows, but not on my Raspberry Pi.
I tried to fix it but i do not know what's wrong, what's the problem?
I just want to know what's broken.

```
#simulatedayymd.py
import os
import asyncio
import discord
import markovify
import time
import random
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
discord.opus.load_opus
client = discord.Client()
token = open("token.txt","r")
token = token.read()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
   print('simulatedayymd')

@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    ayymd = client.get_channel("channelid here")
    if reaction.message.channel == ayymd:
        if reaction.count <= 5:
            msgs = open(f"sim/reactmessages{str(reaction.count)}.txt","r")
            reaction.message.content = reaction.message.content.replace('.','*(^')
            reaction.message.content = str(reaction.message.content)
            history = msgs.read()
            msg = str(f"{history}{reaction.message.content}. ")
            msgs.close()
            try:
                msgs = open(f"sim/reactmessages{str(reaction.count)}.txt","w")
                msgs.write(msg)
                msgs.close()
            except:
                print(f"{str(reaction.message.content)}")
                print('someone used a unicode character')
                msgs = open(f"sim/reactmessages{str(reaction.count)}.txt","w")
                msgs.write(str(f"{history}"))
                msgs.close()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    ayymd = client.get_channel("channelid here")
    if message.channel == ayymd:
        msgs = open("sim\messages.txt","r")
        message.content = message.content.replace('.','*(^')
        message.content = str(message.content)
        history = msgs.read()
        msg = str(f"{history}{message.content}. ")
        msgs.close()
        try:
            msgs = open("sim\messages.txt","w")
            msgs.write(msg)
            msgs.close()
        except:
            print(f"{str(message.content)}")
            print('someone used a fuckin unicode character')
            msgs = open("sim\messages.txt","w")
            msgs.write(str(f"{history}"))
            msgs.close()

    if "b$sim" in message.content:
        n = open("sim\messagesnum.txt","r")
        num = n.read()
        n.close()
        await message.channel.send(f"{num} messages have been recorded")
    
    if "b$sendsim" in message.content:
        simulatedayymd = client.get_channel("channelid here")
        if message.channel == simulatedayymd:
            x = 1
            while x == 1:
                with open("sim\messages.txt") as f:
                    text = f.read()
                with open("sim/reactmessages1.txt") as f:
                    text1 = f.read()
                with open("sim/reactmessages2.txt") as f:
                    text2 = f.read()
                with open("sim/reactmessages3.txt") as f:
                    text3 = f.read()
                with open("sim/reactmessages4.txt") as f:
                    text4 = f.read()
                with open("sim/reactmessages5.txt") as f:
                    text5 = f.read()
                text_model0 = markovify.Text(text)
                text_model1 = markovify.Text(text1)
                text_model2 = markovify.Text(text2)
                text_model3 = markovify.Text(text3)
                text_model4 = markovify.Text(text4)
                text_model5 = markovify.Text(text5)
                model_combo = markovify.combine([ text_model0, text_model1, text_model2, text_model3, text_model4, text_model5 ], [ 1, 0.005, 0.01, 0.015, 0.02, 0.025 ])
                for i in range(1000):
                    message = model_combo.make_short_sentence(2000)
                    msg = message.replace('. ','\n').replace('*(^','.')
                    while '<@' in msg:
                        message = msg.split('<@', 1)
                        mention = message[1].split('>', 1)
                        mntn = mention[0].replace('!','').replace('&','')
                        try:
                            user = str(await client.fetch_user(mntn))
                        except:
                            user = 'invalid-user'
                        try:
                            msg = f"{message[0]}`@{user}`{mention[1]}"
                        except:
                            await simulatedayymd.send(f"<"user here"> Something broke <"emote here">)
                    try:
                        await simulatedayymd.send(f"{msg}")
                    except:
                        print("error happened idk man")
                    time.sleep(random.randint(15,50))

client.run(token)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a `´`-symbol (0x92) in your text file, you try to read in in line 73, which is

```
with open("sim\messages.txt") as f:
    text = f.read()
```

You can open this file in an editor and check if this symbol exists and replace it.